# Is the double dash still the posix standard for long switches?

Tags: posix

I've read several question about double dash:

[Single dashes `-` for single-character options, but double dashes `--` for words?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21852/53092)
[What does `--` (double-dash) mean? (also known as “bare double dash”)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/53092)

However I remember about a teacher 4 years ago telling me that `--` was the posix way of dealing with long switches like `--help` or `--color=`.
Today, I'm using a lot of command where this rule is not respected at all and the best example I can came up with is `find` where no long switches takes a double-dash even with the very annoying `AIX find`.

Was my teacher wrong? or does the rule changes since (which seems unlikely)?
And finally, is there any `posix` rules about the length of option and `-` or `--` ?

Comment: This [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78670/33055) has some background on the syntax of the find command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think [POSIX doesn't define long options](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) :

> Guideline 3:
>      Each option name should be a single alphanumeric character (the alnum
>      character classification) from the portable character set. The -W
>      (capital-W) option shall be reserved for vendor options.
>
> Multi-digit options should not be allowed.

The double dash [is a GNU convention](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html).

In the [POSIX definition of find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47) the "long switches" with single dash are not part of the options, but an expression given as an operand.

Comment: that's indeed interesting

Answer (score 2):

`find` seems to be the exception to the rule. Actually `find` originated outside of the group of initial utility developers for Unix, hence it non-conformant way of using 'long' options.

As so often, the standardization happened only after the use of short-options and long-options had become common practice in **most** programs, and that partly because some routines, or library became available for doing the option parsing (thereby enforcing some non-explicit standard). But of course at that time it was too late to change *existing* programs, like `find`, in a way that would not break scripts. POSIX compliance, with double dashes, is less important than not breaking these scripts.

Backwards compatibility is e.g. also the reason why short options for `tar` can be specified with or without a dash.

Comment: The `kill` and `test` command are two other exceptions. `test` has two-character arguments like `-lt` and `-eq`, although these are more like syntax that just happen to start with a dash. And `ps` is another one that supports options without dashes for legacy compatibility.